# How to call 'invokeMonoMethod' without args?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to call a c# method trough the method invokeMonoMethod however I don`t want to pass any argument to this method:

```
invokeMonoMethod('MonoSanityClient', 'MonoSanityClient', 'Examples', 'getMessage')
```

When I don`t pass argument the message below is returned:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at callMethod (loader.js:106)
    at invokeMonoMethod (loader.js:43)
    at showAlert ((index):77)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):11)
```

After received this message I tried to pass an empty array, on this way:

```
invokeMonoMethod('MonoSanityClient', 'MonoSanityClient', 'Examples', 'getMessage', [])
```

And I received this error:

```
Uncaught abort(). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
```

Comment: Can you maybe share your project somewhere?

Comment: out of curiosity, *why* are you calling this method? Any reason not to use `Blazor.platform.findMethod` (which works well without parameters)?